# Bash Behavior: Using underscores and matching variable names to coerce arrays?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In the code snippet below, I found that, when trying to pass multiple arrays to a function in Bash, I am able to do so using the syntax in my first example, but only if:

1. The array variable names are prefixed with an underscore (_)
2. The array variable names are otherwise identically named in the receiving function as the calling function

```
function list_arrays {
    local _array_one=$1
    local _array_two=$2
    for ip in "${array_one[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip"
    done
    for node in "${array_two[@]}"; do
        echo "$node"
    done
}

function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )
    list_arrays "${array_one[@]}" "${array_two[@]}"
}

main
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
one
two
three
four
five
```

Changing the example slightly to remove the underscores...

```
#!/bin/bash

function list_arrays {
    local array_one=$1
    local array_two=$2
    for ip in "${array_one[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip"
    done
    for node in "${array_two[@]}"; do
        echo "$node"
    done
}

function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )
    list_arrays "${array_one[@]}" "${array_two[@]}"
}

main
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

One last iteration to change the name of the array variables in the list_arrays function

```
#!/bin/bash

function list_arrays {
    local _array_first=$1
    local _array_second=$2
    for ip in "${_array_first[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip"
    done
    for node in "${_array_second[@]}"; do
        echo "$node"
    done
}

function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )
    list_arrays "${array_one[@]}" "${array_two[@]}"
}

main
```

Output:

(no output)

The behavior is extremely convenient but I want to understand what I'm doing before I use this in production scripts. At first I thought this might be related to [pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953833/passing-multiple-distinct-arrays-to-a-shell-function). However, this syntax works in Bash 4.1 which seems to be before pass-by-reference was added.

Comment: did you try to declare the variable as an array (local -a array_first=$1)?

Comment: Are you sure there is no output in the third case? I think what you are seeing in the first two cases is the consequence of [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping). I would expect the same for *any* names for the local variables in `list_arrays` that are distinct from those in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working as expected:

```
function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )
    list_arrays "${array_one[@]}" "${array_two[@]}"
}
```

The arguments passed are not two arrays, but `1 2 3 4 5 one two three four five`.

The function `list_arrays` prints, not the arguments passed but the defined `local array_one` and `local array_two` **in function main**

You can see this by changing your code to

```
function list_arrays {
    # no variable definition
    for ip in "${array_one[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip"
    done
    for node in "${array_two[@]}"; do
        echo "$node"
    done
}

function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )
    # no arguments passed
    list_arrays
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
one
two
three
four
five
```

The variables `local _array_one=$1` and `local _array_two=$2` are not really used at all in your code.

---

When you redefine the variables, as in

```
function list_arrays {
    local array_one=$1 # overwrites main's array_one
    local array_two=$2 # overwrites main's array_two
    for ip in "${array_one[@]}"; do
        echo "$ip"
    done
    for node in "${array_two[@]}"; do
        echo "$node"
    done
}

function main {
    local array_one=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
    local array_two=( one two three four five )

    # arguments passed are 1 2 3 4 5 one two three four five
    list_arrays "${array_one[@]}" "${array_two[@]}"

}
```

now `array_one` is equal to the first argument, `1`, and `array_two` to the second argument, `2`, so the output is

```
1
2
```

Comment: To follow up and make sure I'm understanding you correctly, does this mean that local array_one and local array_two are global variables (despite being declared local)? I'm trying to understand how list_arrays has access to them without them being passed or defined in that function.

Comment: They are local in `main`, and as `list_arrays` is inside `main`, it is in the same (local) scope.